# Is it safe to replace the thermostat when furnace is shut off?

Tags: furnace, thermostat

I need to replace the thermostat in my basement. It is an old style round shape Honeywell mechanical non-programmable thermostat. The gas furnace is turned off (The switch is at OFF now). Is it electrically safe to open it up and replace it without shutting off the power to the whole basement?

Comment: Thermostat is usually a low-cost age circuit (24v)... But I would suggest turning off the furnace circuit breaker, just to be absolutely sure.

Comment: Please be sure to not break it, and not throw it away. Those old, round, very reliable Honeywell's use a mercury switch and that should be properly recycled, not placed in trash. Or you can save it for the antique value it will probably get one day - the mercury is not a problem if it is not broken.

Comment: After reading all comments, I think it is safe to turn off the circuit breaker to the furnace and then do the replacement. Right?

Comment: @PatrickLi Yes, it's always safe (and usually recommended) to turn the power off before doing any work to the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is safe from an injury standpoint to replace that sort of thermostat regardless of the furnace being on or off, since the voltage in the thermostat wiring is 24 V or less.
However, you haven't stated *why* you want to replace it, or what sort of thermostat you intend to install.  If you're looking at a programmable unit, or even a model with Internet connection, be aware that you may need a separate power feed to operate the thermostat itself.  Read the requirements on whatever thermostat model you're considering installing before buying.

Comment: The replacement is exactly the same model.

Comment: @isherwood  Your comment makes no sense whatsoever.  All a thermostat does **is** to open or close a switch.  If you "cross the wires" while replacing the furnace might come on but that's it.

Comment: Fair enough. No need to be so blunt. I wasn't sure whether crossing the various switch circuits could be problematic is all.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I've heard many stories of blown fuses and furnace control modules, where the homeowner reported "*I was just replacing the thermostat, and saw a little spark*". That little spark can be quite expensive. The safest option is to cut power to the system.

Answer (score 0):

You should turn the system off using either the circuit breaker, or the servicemen's switch (if applicable).  If you're working on a live system, there's always the possibility of shorting a wire. This can lead to a blown fuse at best, or a fried furnace control module in the worst case.

While it's true that you're likely not going to hurt yourself, you could indeed damage the system.

Comment: This is just plain false.  The wires to a Honeywell thermostat **are** shorted whenever the furnace is on.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft At no time is `R` ever shorted to ground, `C` , nor is it ever shorted to both `Y` and `W` at the same time. All of these conditions can lead to a blown fuse, or a fried control module.